# How do I ensure a number is within a range?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

Suppose I have some value:

```
double x;
```

and I want to **confine** it to some range `[a, b]` such that the resulting value is within that range:

```
double confine(double x, double a, double b)
{
  if (x < a) return a;
  else if (x > b) return b;
  return x;
}
```

Is there a **single** `boost` or STL function that can do this for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, Boost Algorithm has [`clamp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/algorithm/doc/html/algorithm/Misc.html):

```
double clamped = clamp(x, a, b);
```

It requires only `operator<` or a custom comparator, and guarantees that it is called only once or twice. The documentation points out that with `double` and other floating-point types, NaN could cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from `clamp()`, you could also do this using a one liner in `std::max()` and `std::min()`.

```
double confine(double x, double a, double b) {
  return std::max(a, std::min(x, b));
}
```